# Constant for database name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In my database creation script I have many lines like

```
ALTER DATABASE [database_name_value] SET...
```

because there is often need to create few instances with different names I often have to replace database_name in text editor and this is error-prone I would like to do it more properly by declaring some constant like database_name_constant and assign database name to it once and then use it across script.

Is it possible in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Use some middleware to handle your DB creation and updates, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Did you try `use Database_Name` in the first line of your script?

Comment: @Kanavi no because database does not exist on first line it is dropped and then recreated and there are also instruction like "ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF" and I do not know whether I can strip [dbname] out of this line.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a variable within the script and then run the script in SQLCMD mode

```
:setvar DatabaseName "MyDBName"
```

and then usage

```
ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
```

Comment: I am not only one using this script and as far I know all user copy and paste this script to SQL Management Studio script editor so I have to cope somehow with that. Creating instruction is futile as usual.

Comment: To be honest, if the people that are using this script of not capable of dealing with the change of a parameter  before doing so, they should not really have access to the DB at all in my opinion.

Comment: It looks like best solution but it is not feasible because I must be able to just run script from SQL Management Studio without any prerequisites like setting constants etc.

Comment: it is a matter of communication. I would have to write instruction which no one probably would read and additionally I would like to make it as easy as possible so it means just running a script from SQL Management Studio or SQLDeveloper.

Comment: @Trismegistos  - The script will fail to run if they don't enable `sqlcmd` mode first so that in itself will probably mean people end up reading a comment at the top.

Answer (score 1):

If you're acting from a query *within* the database you want to modify, [`CURRENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) is the option you're looking for.

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET ...
```

Comment: Will it work with "use [dbname]" command so I can change "ALTER DATABASE [Name] SET .." to "USE [Name]; ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET .." ? If yes that would be some step forward but it is not enough. I would ideally want something like @ChrisBint showed but without externally setting variables.

Comment: @Trismegistos - it would work like that, yes, but I've realized that it's only valid for SQL Server 2012, not 2008 as in your question. There aren't any other options in pure T-SQL - most places where SQL Server wants a database name, it wants a *name*, and not a *string*.